Error parsing parameter '--delete': Expected: '=', received: 'EOF' for input:
Issue:
I got the following error when I was trying to delete S3 bucket object versions and markers using the CLI:
Error parsing parameter '--delete': Expected: '=', received: 'EOF' for input:

What I have done:
I used the following command:
- name: Empty s3 Bucket
  run: |
    aws s3api list-object-versions --bucket mybucketname

    aws s3api delete-objects \
        --bucket ${mybucketname} \
        --delete "$(aws s3api list-object-versions \
        --bucket "${mybucketname}" \
        --output=json \
        --query='{Objects: Versions[].{Key:Key,VersionId:VersionId}}')"

    aws s3api delete-objects \
        --bucket ${tgw-lambda-code-${mybucketname} \
        --delete "$(aws s3api list-object-versions \
        --bucket "${mybucketname}" \
        --output=json \
        --query='{Objects: DeleteMarkers[].{Key:Key,VersionId:VersionId}}')"

Question: Can anyone help me understand what's causing this error and how to resolve it?

Your are not closing your parenthesis after list-object-versions. It should be
$(aws s3api list-object-versions)

